# What are the song names in Francesco Napoli's Balla Balla songs?

Tags: pop

Franceso Napoli sang Balla Balla volume 1, 2 and 3. The songs are mixes/combinations of what I think are original Italian songs.

What are the names/artists of the original songs in them?